# Is it secure to scope a query to nothing with limit 0?

Tags: database

I'm using a framework with an expressive query builder and creating scopes for models.  I've run into a situation where the scope is just nothing.  It's a role based scope so if the user has no roles - then there's just no sql to build.  In that kind of situation, is it safe to use limit 0, or should I use 0=1?  Limit 0 seems like the kind of thing a db engine might ignore.

The framework supports swapping out db services.  So my question is kinda ... general db.

Comment: Not all database management systems even support a LIMIT clause at all (namely, Oracle).

Comment: Thanks @ChrisMartin , kinda seems like limit 0 could indicate that no limit is being established, but I hadn't considered that 'limit' itself would be irrelevant. lol